# MySQL and PHP: stored procedure not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've been having a problem with this stored procedure. I'm building a website using PHP and MySQL as database. I'm using the XAMPP framework, which offers phpMyAdmin as a tool to manage the DB.

The procedure tries to update a row in a table after checking that all field have a length of at least 1 character. Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `modificaFornitore`(in idf varchar(10), in nm text, in ind text, in oldidf varchar(10))
BEGIN
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(idf) > 0 AND CHAR_LENGTH(nm) > 0 AND CHAR_LENGTH(ind) > 0) THEN
        UPDATE fornitori SET IDF = idf, Nome = nm, Indirizzo = ind WHERE IDF = oldidf;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO nonexistingtable VALUES ('valore1', 'valore2');
    END IF;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is the PHP code where the procedure is called:

```
$querymodifica = "call modificaFornitore('" . $_POST['idf'] . "', '" . $_POST['nome'] . "', '" . $_POST['indirizzo'] . "', '" . $_POST['vecchioid'] . "')";

if(mysqli_query($dblink, $querymodifica))
    {
        $_SESSION['editfornok'] = 1;
        header("Location: adminfornitori.php?show=4");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['editfornok'] = 0;
        header("Location: adminfornitori.php?show=4");
    }
}
```

The purpose of the insert under the else statement in the procedure is to raise an error in case the if statement fails, so that the error is caught by PHP. I've been using this "trick" in other procedures and it works fine, so I don't feel this is the problem. Anyway, it won't work even without that.

If somebody has got some suggestions, I would be very happy!
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried calling the stored procedure directly to determine whether it's a problem with the procedure or the call?  Could you post some example request data?  Pumping POST values directly into a query string is evil, don't forget to filter those bad boys.

Comment: Better than filtering is to use a prepared statement, which [mysqli supports](http://php.net/mysqli_prepare) (if you can't switch to the newer PDO class). Also, does the MySQL user that the PHP script connects as have EXECUTE permission? Note you can get DB errors using a function provided by the DB extension (e.g. [`mysqli::error`](http://php.net/mysqli_error), [`PDO::errorInfo`](http://php.net/PDO.errorInfo)), though [only admins should ever see DB error messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995351.aspx#securityerrormessages_topic2).

Comment: Also, rather than using a stored procedure for updates (which could easily be skipped by a programmer), consider using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html), (see [MySQL Triggers: How do you abort an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE with a trigger?](http://www.brokenbuild.com/blog/2006/08/15/mysql-triggers-how-do-you-abort-an-insert-update-or-delete-with-a-trigger/)).